# CSS Navbar submenus how to center?

Tags: html, css

Website: http://michaelstricklandconsulting.com

```
nav ul {
background: none;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 1rem;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
}  

nav ul li ul {
background: white;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
min-width: 5rem;
position: absolute;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
margin-top: 1rem;
display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
```

When I hover over my menu, the submenus are off center. I would like for the blue backgrounds to line up with the ul element. Is there a quick way to shift the position of these elements?

```
For Example: What I Do
             Why Vistage and
             Why Michael
             Coaching Academy
```

Comment: Edit the question and add your HTML an external link is not helpful for future visitors.

Comment: well, and if i can suggest, when hover in a dropdown list, it becomes with blue background, and text color to grey, change the text color to white, it makes more clear to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
.nav-horizontal li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px; 
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

To:

```
.nav-horizontal li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0; 
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

man, i entered on your website and i changed this:

```
.nav-horizontal li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

to this:

```
.nav-horizontal li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0;
}
```

and it worked

Comment: Beside the above in this class `.nav li:hover > .sub-menu, .nav li:hover .children` add `left: 0`